# What is the name of this action anime involving magic that I had watched about a couple of years ago?

Tags: kannagi

I don't remember anything but this one scene.

There is a shrine or temple and someone is carrying boxes. They trip or something and these beads fall out. The beads do something that makes the character crazy and not too far off is a couple people reading under a tree. Then a fight breaks out.

The Shrine/Temple was not the main setting of the anime and one of the people under the tree was maybe a little girl.

I believe the person carrying the boxes was a girl with purple hair and the beads were some type of jewellery. I think they were absorbed making her angry or jealous to the point of fighting someone at/near the tree.

I want to say it was a fantasy type setting but I don't remember monsters or such however there is more fighting with magic or magic like abilities.

I watched it only a few years back maybe like 2013, but I'm not certain though it had a "newer" art style.

Comment: I'm sure you can at least remember approximately when you last saw it any maybe what one of the characters looked like.

Answer (score 4):

The anime you are looking for is [Kannagi](http://myanimelist.net/anime/3958/Kannagi), the events you described are from [episode 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Kannagi:_Crazy_Shrine_Maidens_episodes). The purple-haired girl is either Nagi or her sister.

[image]

> Our unlucky protagonist, Jin, uses the trunk of a sacred tree to carve a statue for a school project. When he takes it outside, to his surprise it begins absorbing the surrounding earth and transforms into, hold your breath on this one, a girl! So like all similar setups this guardian deity is pretty pissed that her tree was cut down and lives with Jin while she takes out her anger on squashing bugs....er, cleaning the "Impurities."